# Hide the directory in url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've the links as follow:

```
localhost/a/site/watch/contact/

localhost/a/site/details/about/
```

where .htaccess file is in **site** folder

All I want to do is remove **watch** and **details** from the url like:

```
localhost/a/site/contact/

localhost/a/site/about/
```

**Update**

```
#Options -Indexes 
#Options         +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine   On

#Exclude myadmin directory from the second level links
RewriteRule     ^(myadmin)(/.*)?$ - [L]
RewriteRule     ^(source)(/.*)?$ - [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$    index.php?task=$1 [L]
#Redirect 2nd level links to index.php
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?$    index.php?task=$1&slug=$2 [L]

#Redirect 3rd level links to index.php
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?$    index.php?task=$1&slug=$2&page=$3 [L]

#Redirect 4th level links to index.php
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?$    index.php?task=$1&slug=$2&title=$3&page=$4 [L]
```

I've tried following but this doesnot work

```
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /watch/$1
RewriteBase /a/site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/watch/
RewriteRule /(.*) /watch/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule /(.*) /details/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule /(.+) /watch/$1/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+watch/
RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are there more links starting with `/watch/` or `/details/` or just these 2?

Comment: Refer here- >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: u can do it using routing also by define in route.php

Comment: @anubhava these are only the links

Comment: @Nitu would it be possible to use in the sites that are not using mvc

Comment: Do you already have a .htaccess under `/a/site/` path?

Comment: @anubhava Yes I do have

Comment: ok post the `/a/site/.htaccess` in question

Comment: @anubhava I've added the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Insert these 2 rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line in `/a/site/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ index.php?task=watch&slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(about)/?$ index.php?task=details&slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```